# React Native SVG Build Failure due to incompatible versions

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I'm attempting to build a coworker's code, which involves building with react-native-svg.  Upon build, I get this error:
Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

After narrowing it down, I discovered that this build failure only happens when I try and use version 13.0.0 and up of react-native-svg. For reference, I'm using React native version 0.64.4.  This should be ok according to the version reference on their website:
[version chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp3Dv.png)

I need version 13 at least, otherwise it's too laggy to properly test the code.  What is odd to me is that my coworker is able to build just fine on the same codebase, but maybe that's a difference in operating systems (He is on Mac, I'm on Windows). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

from what I've read on the official github page https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg, version 13.0.0 and above requires react native version >=0.69.0 due to support of fabric, any versions below it will break
[svg version 13.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHsg2.png)

I was in the same situation as you just now and had to opt for installing version 12.5.0 instead.